# How to do bulk insert with ordered false in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm trying to insert documents in bulk, I have created a unique index in my collection and want to skip documents which are duplicate while doing bulk insertion. This can be accomplished with native `mongodb` function:

```
db.collection.insert(
    <document or array of documents>,
    {
        ordered: <boolean>
    }
)
```

I want to accomplish this with `mongoengine`, If anybody knows how to achieve this, please answer the question, thanks.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/

Comment: How to do it in `mongoengine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class like this:

```
class Foo(db.Document):
    bar= db.StringField()    
    meta = {'indexes': [{'fields': ['bar'], 'unique': True}]}
```

And having a list with `Foo` instances `foos=[Foo('a'), Foo('a'), Foo('a')]`
and trying `Foo.objects.insert(foos)` you will get `mongoengine.errors.NotUniqueError`

1st woraround would be delete index from mongodb, insert duplicates, and than ensure index with `{unique : true, dropDups : true}`

2nd workaround would be using underlying pymongo API for bulk ops: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp

Answer (score 1):

For now I am using raw pymongo from mongoengine as a workaround for this. This is the 2nd workaround that @Alexey Smirnov mentioned. So for a mongoengine Document class DocClass you will access the underlying pymongo collection and execute query like below:

```
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError


try:
    doc_list = [doc.to_mongo() for doc in me_doc_list] # Convert ME objects to what pymongo can understand
    DocClass._get_collection().insert_many(doc_list, ordered=False)

except BulkWriteError as bwe:
    print("Batch Inserted with some errors. May be some duplicates were found and are skipped.")
    print(f"Count is {DocClass.objects.count()}.")

except Exception as e:
    print( { 'error': str(e) })
```